# How can I set a custom icon for my atom language plugin

Tags: atom-editor

I created an [Atom](https://atom.io) grammar plugin for my (custom) language. It correctly detects files, does highlighting and snippets, but I cannot figure out how to show a custom file icon for the files with my custom extension. Can't find the relevant documentation either. Can anyone help?